# Experimenting with operators results in ambiguous operator error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am playing around with overloading operators.

All is running fine when I was working with the classes INTEGER and STRING.

```
 class INTEGER {
  private:
    int iValue;

  public:
    INTEGER() {
      iValue = 0;
      }

    int& operator=  (int const& iParam) {
      return iValue = iParam;
      }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const INTEGER& obj)  {
      return os << obj.iValue << endl;
      }

    operator int    () const {
      return iValue;
      }

    operator string () const {
      ostringstream os;
      os << iValue;
      return string(os.str().c_str());
      }
    };


  class STRING {
  private:
    string  strValue;

  public:
    STRING () {
      strValue = "";
      }

    string& operator= (string const& strParam) {
      return strValue = strParam;
      }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const STRING& obj) {
      return os << obj.strValue.c_str() << endl;
      }

    operator int() const {
      istringstream ss(strValue);
      int iValue;
      ss >> iValue;
      return iValue;
      }
  };


int main() {  
    INTEGER i1, i2;
    STRING  s1, s2;

    i1 = 1;    
    s1 = "2";

    i2 = i1 + s1;
    s2 = i2;

    cout << i1 << s1 << i2 << s2;

    return 0;
  }
```

Outputs:

1
  2
  3
  3

But if I expand my class INTEGER with

```
operator double    () const {
  return (double)iValue;
  }
```

(preparings for the next class FLOAT)

the compiler bleats with: ambiguous between "operator INTEGER::int() const" and "operator INITEGER::double() const" at

```
  i2 = i1 + s1;
```

I don't understand my compiler, never used a floating point value. i1 and i2 are from the class INTEGER and s2 is from class STRING and has a int()- operator.

Please light my mind...

Comment: `int& operator=  (int const& iParam) { iValue = iParam; }`  You did not return a value, thus the behavior is *undefined*.

Comment: Are you *sure* it is saying "INTEGER::init" and not "INTEGER::int"?  I think you problem is that without operator double, your code is:  `i2.operator=(i1.operator int() + s1.operator int());`.  With operator double, it can't decide whether to use that, or `i2.operator=(static_cast<int>(i1.operator double() + static_cast<double>(s1.operator int()));`

Comment: This is why casting operators are shunned by many in the C++ community.  Let's say that your code did compile.  First, as pointed out, the behavior is undefined due to not returning a value from functions that are declared to return a value.  But second, can you determine which operator will be called when you run your program, i.e. without using a debugger?  That's the issue -- code that uses casting operators many times calls functions we didn't expect to be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not defined `operator+(INTEGER,STRING)`, so your compiler must do with one of the builtin operators `+`. It can either use `int+int` or `double+int`, since `STRING` has a conversion operator to `int` and `INTEGER` to both `int` and `double`. But these two choices are ambiguous.

IMHO, you should avoid 'funny' conversion operators, since they allow all sorts of code to work unexpectedly, for example

```
STRING s;
std::cout << std::setw(s) << "oops";
```

Instead define the arithmetic operators directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

When inserting this snip, all is fine again - until next obstacle!^^

```
const int operator+(const string& strValue) {
  istringstream ss(strValue);
  int iValue2;
  ss >> iValue2;

  return iValue + iValue2;
  }
```